# What is maximum request size for Google Analytics API?

Tags: php, google-analytics, httprequest, httpresponse, google-analytics-api

What is maximum request size for Google Analytics API? I'm sending Analytics API request to google and getting back 414 Error, saying that request was too long.

**Recently Added:** I understand that http request link must be less than 2000 character, but rises another question. Is it possible to work with Google API using POST?

```
'metrics'=>'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:entrances,ga:visitBounceRate,ga:exitRate,ga:pageValue',
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
    'filters' => $this->_filterLinks,
    'max-results' => '250');
```

**_filterLinks** is links from my db, for which i want to fetch updated statistics.

if  **$this->_filterLinks** is **less then 30** everything is OK if **greater** i'm getting 414 code in response.

> There was an API error : 414 : Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A74527982&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-05-08&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AuniquePageviews%2Cga%3AavgTimeOnPage%2Cga%3Aentrances%2Cga%3AvisitBounceRate%2Cga%3AexitRate%2Cga%3ApageValue&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2F%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fpflanzen-lexikon%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fgarten-pflanzen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fratgeber.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fwespen-vertreiben-so-geht-s.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbalkon-pflanzen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fratgeber%2Fpflanzengedichte.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fpflanzen-lexikon%2Fentry%2Fgef%C3%A4%C3%9Fsporenpflanzen%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbalkonpflanzen-welche-passen-zusammen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fmagazin.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fzimmer-pflanzen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fder-tulpenbaum-ein-neuer-gartentrend.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fpflanzen-lexikon%2Fentry%2Findischer%2Bspinat%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbalkon-pflanzen%2Faffenbaum-die-aussergewohnlichkeit-in-person.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fmagazin%2Fpflanzengeschichten%2Flena-s-tulpenbaum.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fwespennest-darf-ich-es-selbst-entfernen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fwhere%2Fstandort%2Fsonne-bis-halbschatten%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fzantedeschia.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbougainvillea-uberwintern-so-einfach-geht-s.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbrombeeren-schneiden-ist-wahrlich-keine-grosse-kunst.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fcatalogsearch%2Fresult%2F%3Fq%3Dtulpenbaum%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fcyperus-alternifolius-zyperngras.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Feine-feuerbohne-gegen-ein-feuriges-gemut.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Ffriedrich-ruckert-und-sein-gedicht-uber-das-erdbeerstrauchlein.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Flupinen-die-bluhenden-alleskonner.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fmoos-im-rasen-so-wird-dein-rasen-wieder-gesund.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fpflanzenschadlinge-im-garten-was-tun.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbaume-straucher%2Fpage%2F4.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fcatalogsearch%2Fresult%2F%3Fq%3Dbuchsbaum%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fpflanzenlust-blog.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Facorus-gramineus-zwergkalmus.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fbaume-straucher%2Fkoniferen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fclematis-schneiden-1-pflanze-3-unterschiedliche-typen.html%2Cga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Fdatenschutz&max-results=250&key=AIzaSyDbutx9YEo6rgeqxqdLHcO7IEgEUD2Pvwg:
>   (414)           Error 414 (Request-URI Too
>   Large)!!1   
>       *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7%
>   auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* >
>   body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px
>   no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0
>   22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a
>   img{border:0}@media screen and
>   (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png)
>   no-repeat}@media only screen and
>   (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png)
>   no-repeat 0% 0%/100%
>   100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and
>   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png)
>   no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100%
>   100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}
>
> **414.** That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL
>   `/analytics/v3/data/ga`... is too large to process. 
>   That’s all we know.

Am i Getting it from Google or from my local? 
If from my local there shouldn't be any google error message like **That’s all we know.**
Am I doing right query? Is there any way to bypass this issue or limit? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your getting a 414 from the Google API I think your either getting it from apache or the web browser.

> Under Apache, the limit is a configurable value, LimitRequestLine.
>   Change this value to something larger than its default of 8190 if you
>   want to support a longer request URI.

Google Analytics API limits the number of dimensions and metrics you can send but there is no limit to how big your filter can be. (Assuming you are stringing them together using `and` and `or` a single filter value can be max 128 or you will get a 404 bad request error)

But assuming you keep tacking them on you will probably end up blowing out the limit set by apache. (Being that your not really sending the request though a web browser I wonder if you could set apache higher to handle the request. A web browser can max handle 2000 but this might not be an issue in this case because your not going though a web browser. But that will depend on if Google will even except a request that long.)  I will have to test this.

Edit Post:
No The request to get data back form the API is a Get not a Post.  Post would be sending information to the server not Requesting the server to give you information back.

Comment: thanks for help! As I understand, I will need to download apache source->edit httpd.h->DEFAULT_LIMIT_REQUEST_LINE to greater value->recompile apache->Reinstall Apache?

Comment: Its worth a try. I don't have access to an Apache server that I can mess around with the configuration on. So I cant help you test it, If it does work I would love to know for future reference.  it should be in the httpd.conf  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,84025,84076

Comment: I will test it today, i hope it is best solution, and also hope even after successful Apache compilation google will accept longer uri!

Comment: you shouldn't have to compile apache to change the httpd.conf  just restart the server.

Comment: It should be easier, to do this with `nginx`, where you can set a max limit without recompiling it (apache sucks anyways...), see http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#large_client_header_buffers

Answer (score -1):

The max request size is 10,000. But the response will tell you how many records are present and you can loop and request additional pages with "start-index" parameter. So with four calls you can request the 40,000 entries. But be sure to catch HTTP quota errors and delay your calls if you exceeded the requests per second quota.

Comment: I think you mean the max response size is 10,000. I don't see any documentation for the length of the request. At least not in v3 API.

Comment: It is both, as you cannot request more than 10,000 and therefore you will not get back more than that.

Comment: No, I think you missed the entire purpose of the question. He was running into an error regarding the size of his request url (the thing where all the parameters go), which has no bearing on how many objects are intended to be returned. Notice in his request he even has max-results set to 250. He doesn't even want more than 10,000 entries returned, so what does your answer have to do with any of this? There is no limit imposed by the Google API regarding the request size (see url size). But there may be by your browser or webserver framework. Unless you can show that page in the documentation.

Comment: You are right - he was talking about the URL length - my mistake.